# How can a declaration conflict with itself?

Tags: c++, g++, solver

This is the error I'm getting when trying to compile some code that uses taucs (not my code):

```
.../taucs/src/taucs.h:554: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct taucs_ccs_matrix taucs_ccs_matrix’
.../taucs/src/taucs.h:554: error: ‘taucs_ccs_matrix’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct taucs_ccs_matrix taucs_ccs_matrix’
```

wat?  It is conflicting with itself?

After I pinched myself, I created a test header and put in a conflicting definition, just to make sure I was right about this:

In file testit.h:

```
#include "somethingelse.h"

typedef struct
{
  int n;
} foobar;
```

In file somethingelse.h:

```
typedef struct
{
  int n;
} foobar;
```

Sure enough, I get:

```
testit.h:6: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct foobar foobar’
somethingelse.h:4: error: ‘foobar’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct foobar foobar’
```

Or if I have this in testit.h:

```
typedef struct
{
  int n;
} foobar;

typedef struct
{
  int n;
} foobar;

testit.h:9: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct foobar foobar’
testit.h:4: error: ‘foobar’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct foobar foobar’
```

The line number is always different -- a declaration can't conflict with itself.  I don't get it.  Anyone ever seen this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be that your header file (`.../taucs/src/taucs.h`), which contains the declaration, is (directly or indirectly) included twice by two separate `#include` directives?

Comment: I decided to give the checkmark to this answer since it came first.

Answer (score 17):

Is the single header included in multiple source files? If so, you need to wrap it in "include guards" like so:

```
#ifndef TAUCS_H
#define TAUCS_H

//Header stuff here

#endif //TAUCS_H
```

Comment: You should avoid the leading double underscores, though.  Those names are reserved.

Comment: So are the trailing double underscores. A correct form would be `TAUCS_H`. C and C++ programmers won't use macros with _H suffixes for other purposes, so this is safe enough without further decoration.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
   int n;
} foobar;

typedef struct
{
   int n;
} foobar;

testit.h:9: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct foobar foobar’
testit.h:4: error: ‘foobar’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct foobar foobar’
```

In this example you give 2 declarations of foobar. The compiler does not know which one to choose - so it bails out with conflicting declaration. You can't declare the same thing twice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat the definition.  C++ allows a definition to only appear one time.  What you can do is repeat a declaration.

A `typedef` is always a definition.  So the first thing I would recommend is giving the `struct` proper a name (and since this is C++, a typedef does not add any benefit so just drop the typedef):

```
// file1.h
struct foobar
{
    int n;
};
```

Next, that should be in exactly one file.  If you have files that only use pointers to foobar, you can **repeat the declaration** (just not the definition):

```
// file2.h

// This is just a declaration so this can appear as many times as
// you want
struct foobar;

void doit(const foobar *f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue linting my code and it was *not* double declaration of a type. PC-Lint complained about the same typedef being used in mixed C and C++ code. I could fix that by avoiding the same declaration in C *and* C++ files. Hope that helps someone.